# How to export custom object list/details?

Tags: apex, trigger, custom-object, data-export

how to export custom object list/details? can we achieve this in apex coding?
i want to know how many custom objects are there in org with their names in excel.

Comment: Hope the below blogs will help you to get the list of objects using APEX CODE.

http://www.infallibletechie.com/2012/08/export-using-apex-code-in-salesforce.html

https://douglascayers.com/2016/03/20/salesforce-easy-ways-to-export-data-as-csv/

http://www.appshark.com/how-to-export-data-in-excel-using-visualforce/

Comment: What kind of details you want to export? Is it metadata or records of a particular object?

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Object Metadata Snapshot tool** from Appexchange to export object details to excel.

or

[**Etherios - EasyDescribe**](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000018leZEAQ)